# Redirect to the login URL when user enters default address in Django?

Tags: django

I have this URL which takes user to the `login` page:

```
url(r'^login_backend', 'fileupload.backend.login_backend'),
```

Since the user doesn't want to remember:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_backend
```

I want to redirect `http://127.0.0.1:8000 to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_backend` without affecting any other activity. I have this decorator above every view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login_backend/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django [generic redirect_to view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to). Add following in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
                  ('^$', 'redirect_to', {'url': 'login_backend/'}),
              )
```

Comment: Not working! My URL looks like this: 
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^upload_file/', 'fileupload.views.upload_file'),
    url(r'^sync/', 'fileupload.backend.sync')

Comment: @user2032220 try with `/login_backend/`. BTW, your urls doesn't seem to have this.

Comment: When user types http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I want to redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_backend